# JavaFX webview delay between loading pages

Tags: java, webview, javafx

So, I have a webview and want to load 2 (or any number > 1) pages one after another. But the page change has to happen not immediately after the previous page has loaded, but after a certain time. For example:

```
public void load() 
{
    engine.load("link1");
    //need to wait some time here
    engine.load("link2");
    //need to wait some time here
    engine.load("link3");
}
```

I've tried to make a thread sleep when page is finished loading:

```
engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue observableValue, Worker.State o, Worker.State o2) {
            if (o2.equals(Worker.State.SUCCEEDED)) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

But it doesn't work, as engine.load() doesn't wait until the page is loaded (because we have event listener for that). Another minus side of this is that Thread.sleep() blocks GUI and the whole thread, therefore I cannot place it between loading links.

Is there any solution? To place a delay **after** a page has loaded and **before** starting to load the next page.

Regards,

Ivan

Answer (score 2):

```
Thread.sleep(n);
```

It is the thread which draw the window, that's why it will block the GUI.

The solution for your problem is to load all the pages in a separated thread.
BUT you cannot load a page if you're not in the javaFX thread...
The solution is to load this using the Platform.runLater() function.

So you have to implement the following code into a separated thread which can sleep without blocking the GUI.

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        webView.getEngine().load("http://www.my.url/");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As Engine points out in his answer, `Thread.sleep` blocks the UI updating thread, which isn't what you want.  Basically, never sleep on the UI thread.

I suggest replacing your Thread.sleep call a [PauseTransition](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html).

This has the advantage that the JavaFX animation subsystem handles the threading for you, ensuring that your code is always called on the UI thread at the appropriate time, so you never need to worry about threading . . . not needing to worry about threading is always good in my opinion . . .

```
engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
  new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(
        ObservableValue observableValue, 
        Worker.State oldState, 
        Worker.State state) {
      if (state.equals(Worker.State.SUCCEEDED)) {
        PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(3));
        pause.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
          @Override
          public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            webView.getEngine().load("http://www.mynext.url/");
          }       
        });
        pause.play();
      }
    }
  }
);
```

You may want some extra logic in there to recover from stuff such as if the Worker state is FAILED so that your slideshow effect doesn't stop working the first time you get a connection error to a given url.

If you are not sure if you are on the UI thread, add a debugging statement where you are thinking of sleeping:

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

If the name is "FX Application Thread" then, you should use another mechanism such as the animation framework or a [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) to handle the pause.